# Can someone identify this LEGO Model? Brown Technic set with huge dark grey wheels?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

Can someone identify the name and/or set number of this LEGO Model?

[image: Model]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's set [4481 - Hailfire Droid](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4481-1&name=Hailfire%20Droid&category=%5BTechnic%5D%5BStar%20Wars%5D%5BStar%20Wars%20Episode%202%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D). You've got it tilted vertically, it needs to rotate 90 degrees - the black rocket launch pods need to be on top.

[image]